# How to convert jsonAST.Jint to int

Tags: json, scala, type-conversion

I am attempting to learn Scala, and I'm trying to parse a JSON file. I have two lines of code:

```
var jVal:JValue = parse(json);
val totalCount:Int = (jVal \\ "totalCount").asInstanceOf[Int];
```

However, `(jVal \\ "totalCount")` returns a `JInt` instead of an int. If I print it as a string, it looks like `"JInt(38)"`.

How on earth do I convert this to a regular int? My current code throws an exception saying that

> `net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$JInt` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Integer`

I've scoured the internet, but I can't find any answers. I would really prefer not to manually parse and remove the "JInt()" part of the string just to get it as an integer.

Surely I am missing a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Since [`JInt`](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/index.html#net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$$JInt) is a case class, a convenient way to extract the value is using an extractor expression, either in a `match`:

```
myJValue match {
  case JInt(x) => /* do something with x */
  case JString(s) => /* do something with s */
  /* etc. */
}
```

or just an assignment statement, when you know what type to expect:

```
val JInt(totalCount) = (jVal \\ "totalCount")
```

This will define `totalCount` to be the value of "totalCount" in your JSON. Note that it will be of type `BigInt`. If you want to, you can convert your `BigInt` to an `Int` with the [`toInt`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.math.BigInt@toInt:Int) method. But if your number is too big for an `Int`, this method will give you a different number instead of an error. So if huge numbers are at all a possibility, you'll want to check first with `isValidInt`.

---

You can also get the value using the `num` field or `values` method, but in your code that's harder to work with. To use `num`, you'd have to do a cast of your `JValue` to `JInt`. And if you don't cast to `JInt`, you won't know the type of the result of `values`.

Comment: When I do val totalCount = (jval \\ "totalCount").num.toInt, it says it can't resolve symbol num. I'm not sure why it doesn't exist, I am importing net.liftweb.json._ and net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats.

Comment: I probably should not have edited my initial comment, but it has changed to reflect my current findings.

Comment: If that is the case, what is the correct way to parse a JSON file in Scala? Part of the JSON file is as follows: {
    "totalCount": 38,
    "page": 1,
    "transactions": [{
        "Date": "2013-12-22",
        "Ledger": "Phone & Internet Expense",
        "Amount": "-110.71",
        "Company": "SHAW CABLESYSTEMS CALGARY AB"
    },

Comment: @ArthurLee I have a new suggestion. I think this one actually works.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much. Would it look similar if I wanted to get a Transaction object (that I have defined) out of the JSON file, except with val JArray(transactions) = (jVals \\ "transactions");?

Comment: Yes, the [API](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/index.html#net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$$JArray) says `transactions` would be a `List[JValue]`.